# Spring MVC request / command objects

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, url-routing

Is there a convenient way to turn something like this..

```
@RequestMapping("/some/action/{q}/...")
public void doSomething(@PathVariable("q"), oh, my, god, a, billion, annotated parameters) { .. }
```

Into something like this..

```
@RequestMapping("/some/action/{q}/...")
public void doSomething(NiceEncapsulatingRequetObject request) { .. }
```

With Spring MVC?

Answer (score 0):

After checking the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.html), it doesn't seem like it is supported out of the box. You could try to create your own [HandlerMethodArgumentResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.html) which gives you this feature. You might run into some issues since you'll need a circular reference between your implementation and the  `HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite` instance. Nevertheless I think it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes spring supports this out of the box, it is usualy refered to as bean binding.
Basicly you create an object with paramaters with the same name,
so if you have a paramater "q", your object should contain a private string q with both getter and setter present. It's also prefered not to use any constructors.

Spring will just fill in the paramaters it has in your object and pass it via the method's paramater.

Answer (score 0):

You can create you own object like `NiceEncapsulatingRequetObject` and it's attributes should be `String oh, Integer my` etc. If you send the request with the exact names it will work